# Regex match zero or one group

Tags: regex

I have filenames in format `<pod-name>_<namespace-name>_<container-name>-<dockerid>.log`

For example:

```
pod-name_namespace-name_container-name-7a1d0ed5675bdb365228d43f470fcee20af5c8bea84dd6d886b9bf837a9d358c.log
pod-name_namespace-name-1234567890_container-name-7a1d0ed5675bdb365228d43f470fcee20af5c8bea84dd6d886b9bf837a9d358c.log
```

Actually this is the k8s container's log files.

The `namespace-name` **may** contain numeric postfix that represents automation system run id (`github.run_id` - 10 digits number).

I need to parse filenames with regex to extract pod name, namespace name without run id, run id, container name and docker id.

Regex based on default fluentbit kubernetes [parser](https://github.com/fluent/fluent-bit/blob/master/conf/parsers.conf#L126) that I need to change for our usage:

```
(?<pod_name>[a-z0-9](?:[-a-z0-9]*[a-z0-9])?(?:\.[a-z0-9]([-a-z0-9]*[a-z0-9])?)*)_(?<namespace_name>[^_]+)(-(?<run_id>\d{10,}))_(?<container_name>.+)-(?<docker_id>[a-z0-9]{64})\.log$
```

https://rubular.com/r/CROBxpHHgX5UZx

The regex above parses well filenames that contains namespace with run id, but fails to parse namespace without run id:

```
pod-name_namespace-name_container-name-7a1d0ed5675bdb365228d43f470fcee20af5c8bea84dd6d886b9bf837a9d358c.log
```

https://rubular.com/r/6MSQsnuGzrkVJG

In this case the `run_id` should be empty string

How to fix it that it match both cases?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
(?<pod_name>[a-z0-9](?:[-a-z0-9]*[a-z0-9])?(?:\.[a-z0-9]([-a-z0-9]*[a-z0-9])?)*)_(?<namespace_name>[^_]+?)(-(?<run_id>\d{10,}))?_(?<container_name>.+)-(?<docker_id>[a-z0-9]{64})\.log$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/zBKsfl/1).

The main point is to make two changes in `(?<namespace_name>[^_]+)(-(?<run_id>\d{10,}))` part:

- make the `[^_]+` pattern lazy, so that it could match as few chars other than `_` as possibe, i.e. add a `?` after `+`
- make the `(-(?<run_id>\d{10,}))` part optional by adding a `?` quantifier after the group.